# EXPO error, I want to build the app. But "SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I am studying through EXPO.
Recently, I entered

```
`expo build:ios`
```

for building an app.
But an error occurs. 
The following errors occur:

```
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
Reason: Unknown reason, raw: "SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed"
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Also, I tried building through exp.

```
exp build:ios
```

In addition, the following error occurs:

```
[16:47:44] Validating Credentials...
[16:48:11] Error while gathering & validating credentials
[16:48:11] Reason:Unknown reason, raw:"getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known"
[16:48:11] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

I need a teacher to help me.
Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug which is solved in its new latest version.
Try:`npm install -g expo-cli` or `npm install -g expo-cli@3.11.7` and confirm expo --version gives `3.11.7`